# Does the ASHWID change if the BIOS is upgraded?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, bios

Microsoft provides a method to get an ASHWID (App Specific Hardware ID) which has many components, one of which is some kind of BIOS ID.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx

Does that BIOS ID change if the user upgrades the BIOS on their computer?

**RANT:**

I don't understand why Microsoft makes getting a unique ID for an OS installation so complicated for Windows Store Apps. Android is so simple, when the Android OS boots the very first time they generate a GUID (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) that never changes. Why doesn't Microsoft do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that value changes with factory reset in Android.

Second of all, try checking out [EasClientDeviceInformation.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id.aspx). It uses a combination of the MachineId (local user group SID), the UserId, and the Package Id, but doesn't give you the whole thing.

This is good because Thirdly, giving devs access to use them directly to generate things like crypto keys can lead to other apps getting your apps keys, like has happened on many iOS devices. By limiting what device id's you can use, they're making it so that you must use a system resource that is literally only accessible from inside of a given application with a given Id from inside that user's account. The Windows Store is very strongly sandboxed for exactly this reason. While it can be a pain sometimes, it makes the platform much more secure, which is a huge boon.